# Angular dropdown value not getting selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have a list of food category dropdown values which are fixed values. Then I have a table for a list of food items and there is a field for foodcategory which classifies which category this item falls. The food category is being mapped based on Guid but is being displayed in readable format for the user. However, Im failing to do the mapping. Can you please check what is the issue?

Here is my code snippet.

```
    <tr *ngFor="let food of foodItems" id="{{food.Guid}}" class="alternate-row">
      <td><label>{{food.foodName}}</label></td>
      <td><label>{{food.foodDescription}}</label></td>
      <td>
        <form class="table_form" [formGroup]="tableForm" (ngSubmit)="onTableFormSubmit(tableForm.value)">
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="foodCategorySelect" (change)="onTableFormSubmit(tableForm.value, food.Guid)">
            <option *ngFor="let foodCategory of foodCategoryList" [value]="foodCategory.Guid" [selected]="foodCategory.Guid == food.category">
              {{ foodCategory.categoryName }}
            </option>
          </select>    
        </form> 
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my logged value data:

```
    foodCategoryList
    0: 
    Guid: "b6b64fba-1879-44fb-8a8d-1b26c2229367"
    categoryName: "Starter"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    1: 
    Guid: "ba9e3828-ddf0-4db4-bff2-2ec668d973d0"
    categoryName: "Dessert"
    [[Prototype]]: Object

    foodList
    0: 
    foodName: "Chicken Wings"
    Guid: "ec34ce1f-5274-4d32-a17f-4a518fef9a1f"
    foodDescription: "Delicious spicy chicken wings served with sauce"
    category: "b6b64fba-1879-44fb-8a8d-1b26c2229367" --starter
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Value is being null. I resorted to this approach as formcontrol was not working :/

Comment: Since you are using the Reactive form, you should set the value for form control instead of using the `[selected]` attribute. And from your code, you are iterating the `foodItems` array and this will result in multiple `FormGroup` being created but you are referring to a single `FormGroup` instance (`tableForm`), which I don't think this is correct. Also, would be great if you can reproduce the issue in StackBlitz. Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun, can you  provide me with a  sample code how to tackle it please?

Comment: "I'm failing to do this mapping" is not a detailed enough problem description.